# VBA to find the last value in a row greater than 0 then return the header of that column as the value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet which has over 1000 rows of data. Column A consists of names and Row 1 has dates going across the top of over 500 columns.

I have another sheet which is a copy of column A and I want to put the date of the last entry of data that is greater than 0 into column B.

I want to do the following:

1. Find the last cell in each row that is greater than 0 (starting from the second row up to the 1500th row)
2. Then I want to have the date of that entry listed into column B of another sheet where I have the same names listed.

I'm completely stuck with this. I have tried to get VBA and formula's to work but I can only seem to get them to bring up the value of the last cell and not the date of the entry. An exmaple of one formula is below:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/('Sheet1'!B2:ARJ2<>""),'Sheet1'!B2:ARJ2)
```

Hopefully, I would like a VBA solution, but I will take any solution right now!

Thanks,

Comment: the formula should be `=LOOKUP(2,1/('ME Counts'!F2:ARJ2<>""),'ME Counts'!F$1:ARJ$1)`

Comment: @ScottCraner Works perfectly for the last value - doesnt help me with the last value above 0 though

Comment: Change `<>""` to instead be `>0`